# Помогите составить регулярное выражение для разбора строки с символом и двумя координатами

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Уже долго не могу распарсить строку, типа *(h или v)? ((double double double double) или ((double,double) (double,double)))*

например:

- h 1 1 100.5 100 (в результате S='h', x1=1, y1=1, x2=100.5, y2=100)
- v 1,1 100,100.5
- 1,1 100.5,100 (в результате S=defaultS, point1 = (1,1), point2 = (100.5,100))
- 1 1 100 100.5

Comment: И что здесь парсить надо? Если просто разбить строку по пробелам - вас это устроит? Т.е. какой результат вы ожидаете получить?

Comment: Split я и сам могу сделать :), только строк кода будет много на все проверки. Нет, мне конкретно надо из строки получить необязательный символ 'h' или 'v', если он есть и 4 дробных (или целочисленных) значения или две точки по два значения.

Comment: Полагаю, что то типа `"((h|v) )?(\d+(\.\d+) \d+(\.\d+) \d+(\.\d+) \d+(\.\d+))|(\d+(\.\d+)\,\d+(\.\d+) \d+(\.\d+)\,\d+(\.\d+))"` но нужно тестить

Comment: @AgentFire, тестирую тут https://regex101.com/ не разбирает (

Comment: Разбейте строку по пробелам, если длина полученного массива 5, то S = arr[0], если 4, то дефаульт, ну и остальные значения заполняются тоже на основе длины полученного массива.

Comment: ^^ чуть сложнее - у него разделители запятые могут быть. но ход мыслей похож :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, спасибо за разъяснение логики, но логика мне и так ясна. Я в комментарии выше писал, зачем мне нужно распарсить строку регулярками.

Comment: lf;'t так https://regex101.com/r/xW7iY9/3

Comment: @splash58 лучше привязать конец регулярного выражения к `$`, тогда 4 последних числа гарантированно попадут в группы 2-5, а будет ли необязательная группа 1 будет зависеть только от текста.

Comment: @ReinRaus согласен, вот версия https://regex101.com/r/xW7iY9/4

Comment: @splash58, вроде, то что нужно! ) Оформите как ответ, я приплюсую! )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Совместными усилиями на основе комментария AgentFire и совета ReinRaus получилась такая регулярка

```
^(?:(h|v) )?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\s+|\s*,\s*)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\s+|\s*,\s*)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*$
```

`(?:(h|v) )?` - захватывает необязательный признак h/v

`(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - захватывает целое число или число с плавающей точкой

`(?:\s+|\s*,\s*)` - разделитель чисел - запятая или пробелы

[Демо и объяснение поподробнее](https://regex101.com/r/xW7iY9/4)

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Было бы совсем замечательно, если бы первая группа возвращала пустую строку, если там ничего нет. Это бы сократило дальнейший код с 5 строк до 1й :).  Но это, наверное, невозможно

Comment: по крайней мере, неочевидно :(

Comment: а, все норм, в c# класс Matches возвращает все группы, но у первой группы Success = False! )

Comment: @iRumba ну и отлично!

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день. Вот решение:

```
(h|v)?[ ,]?([\d.]+)
```

Посмотреть в интерактивном редакторе:

https://regex101.com/r/rO0zT3/3

Если синтаксис - pcre, можете дать скобкам имена

Comment: Почти то, что я и хотел, но парсит даже это *v 1 v 1 v 100.5 v 100* . А ведь я сначала все же проверяю строку на валидность.

Comment: Ну, проверка валидности в вопросе отсутствовала, только парсинг)

Comment: Тут такое дело: ответы из только ссылки не считаются хорошими ответами, т.к. ссылки имеют свойство ломаться со временем. Поэтому я вашу регулярку скопировал прямо в ответ. В будущих ответах, пожалуйста, публикуйте код сразу в ответе ( а ссылку можно оставить как полезное дополнение). Кстати, сервис отличный, не знал про такой.

Comment: @MiKeBu, так и парсит неправильно :)

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, про ссылки - спасибо, учту

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте

```
([h|v] )?\d{1,4}([:punct:]\d{1,4})? \d{1,4}(\.\d{1,4})? \d{1,4}(\.\d{1,4})? \d{1,4}(\.\d{1,4})?
```

Comment: К сожалению не подошло. :(

Comment: вот только не плохо бы вместо запятых пробелы поставить а потом к полученной строке и регулярку применять\

Comment: Да не в запятых дело. Это годится только для проверки на валиндность, а не для парсинга.

Answer (score 0):

Подошло вот что

```
(^([h,v]) )?((\d*(\.\d+)?)(\s|\,|$))((\d*(\.\d+)?)(\s|\,|$))((\d*(\.\d+)?)(\s|\,|$))((\d*(\.\d+)?)(\s|\,|$))
```

Проблема в том, что слишком много подгрупп получилось. Я ожидал что будет

- S = group[0] OR default
- x1 = group[1]
- y1 = group[2]
- x2 = group[3]
- y2 = group[4]

Но в результате для строки *v 1,1 100.9,100* получил это

- 1. [0-2]   `v`
- 2. [0-1]   `v`
- 3. [2-4]   `1,`
- 4. [2-3]   `1`
- 6. [3-4]   `,`
- 7. [4-6]   `1`
- 8. [4-5]   `1`
- 10. [5-6]
- 11. [6-12]  `100.9,`
- 12. [6-11]  `100.9`
- 13. [9-11]  `.9`
- 14. [11-12] `,`
- 15. [12-15] `100`
- 16. [12-15] `100`
- 18. [15-15] ``*

Так что вопрос остается открытым.

Comment: посмотрите мой последний комментарий

Answer (score 0):

так все очевидно же

```
([h|v] )?\d{1,4}([:punct:]\d{1,4})? \d{1,4}(\.\d{1,4})? \d{1,4}(\.\d{1,4})? \d{1,4}(\.\d{1,4})
```

Comment: Смотрите ответ от пользователя s_klepcha. Там в комментариях я написал, почему такое решение не подходит. Сравните с ответом, помеченным как решение. Вдруг будет полезно. Спасибо.